# CSS border-image showing blurry

Tags: html, image, css, border

I have the following image which I am trying to set as an image border (I've added the red just so that you can see it properly — the real version is trimmed with transparent bg)

Dimensions: 363 x 10

[image]

I am trying to set it as a border image just for the top border (for the time being):

```
.panel {
   background: #fff;
   background: none;
   border-radius: 0;
   border-width: 10px;
   border-style: solid;
   border-image: url('../image/marker-white-01-reversed.png');
   border-image-slice: 15%;
}
```

If I set `border-image-slice: 15%;` the general shape of the top border looks correct (I think), but it looks really blurry:
[image]

Can anyone see why this is? Originally I left `border-image-slice` out but the image was only showing in the corners... and played about with different values but none seemed to give me the correct result

Comment: What is the effect you're trying to achieve?

Comment: @ErenTantekin I'm basically just trying to get the top border to look like the first image (the one of the image file)

Answer (score -1):

```
.panel { 
  background: #fff; 
  background: none; 
  border-radius: 0; 
  border-width: 10px; 
  border-style: solid; 
  border-image: url('../image/marker-white-01-reversed.png'); 
  border-image-slice: 15%; 
}
```

Look at your code..
Radius 0 and image slice 15% and solid border..
That is you have to have such an image.